# Print sequence and value ordered by the value

Tags: python, sequence

I have a code that takes all possible combinations of sequences of 6 to 10 cards colored Red or Black. With the help of a mathematical equation, a given `surprise` metric is calculated based on two drawn card sequences. Here is the code:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement 

deckOrder=[]

box_1=['R','B']
comb = combinations_with_replacement(box_1, 6) 
for i in list(comb): 
  deckOrder.append(i)

comb = combinations_with_replacement(box_1, 7) 
for i in list(comb): 
  deckOrder.append(i)
 
comb = combinations_with_replacement(box_1, 8) 
for i in list(comb): 
  deckOrder.append(i)

comb = combinations_with_replacement(box_1, 9) 
for i in list(comb): 
  deckOrder.append(i)

comb = combinations_with_replacement(box_1, 10) 
for i in list(comb): 
  deckOrder.append(i)

outcome = []

for i in range(len(deckOrder)):
  for j in range(len(deckOrder)):

#Draw

first_draw = deckOrder[i]
second_draw = deckOrder[j]

#Before first draw

initial_estimate = 0.5
initial_variance = 1/12

#After first draw 

r_count = first_draw.count('R')
b_count = first_draw.count('B')


alpha = 1 + r_count
beta = 1 + b_count


e_of_theta = alpha/(alpha+beta)

surprise = ((e_of_theta - initial_estimate)**2)/(initial_variance)

var_theta = (alpha * beta)/ ((alpha + beta) **2 *(alpha + beta + 1))   

#After second draw 

r_count = second_draw.count('R')
b_count = second_draw.count('B')

new_alpha = alpha + r_count 
new_beta = beta + b_count 

new_e_of_theta = new_alpha/(new_alpha + new_beta)

surprise = ((new_e_of_theta - e_of_theta)**2)/var_theta

#Export

new_list = [surprise]

for a in new_list:
  outcome.append(a)

order = sorted(outcome)
print(*order,sep='\n')
```

The code right now only displays the `suprise` value. Is there any way I could display both the sequences used and the value so I know which value belongs to which sequence in an ordered fashion (by `surprise` val)?

Comment: not really sure what you are trying to achieve here. Can you maybe rephrase?

Comment: Yes, of course! The general task is that there are 2 types of cards, red and blue. The cards are drawn twice, the draw must be 6-10 cards. The first part of the code generates all the possible combinations for 6-10 cards. The second part of the code takes those combinations and puts them through an equation that calculates surprise. By running the code, you get the values of surprise for the possible combinations. But the problem is that I don't know which value is generated by which sequence. I only get a list of values. Is there any way I can see which values are generated by which sequence?

Comment: I hope that made sense, please let me know if I should try to explain it in a better way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in a previous answer, a good candidate to solve this question is by using the `OrderedDict` where `surprise` is used as the key and the sequences are stored as the values. The original snippet is quite unorganized though and the indentation was flawed. Here is my suggestion for the solution:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement 
from collections import OrderedDict

deckOrder, card_colors, draw_num_cards = [], ['R', 'B'], [x for x in range(6, 11)]

for num_cards in draw_num_cards:
    combs = combinations_with_replacement(card_colors, num_cards)
    deckOrder.extend(list(combs))

outcome = {}
initial_estimate = 0.5
initial_variance = 1/12
        
for i in range(len(deckOrder)):
    #Draw
    first_draw = deckOrder[i]
    
    #After first draw 
    r_count = first_draw.count('R')
    b_count = first_draw.count('B')

    #Before first draw
    alpha = 1 + r_count
    beta = 1 + b_count
    
    for j in range(len(deckOrder)):
        #Draw
        second_draw = deckOrder[j]

        e_of_theta = alpha/(alpha+beta)
        surprise = ((e_of_theta - initial_estimate)**2) / (initial_variance)
        var_theta = (alpha * beta) / ((alpha + beta)**2 * (alpha + beta + 1))   
        
        #After second draw 
        r_count = second_draw.count('R')
        b_count = second_draw.count('B')
        
        new_alpha = alpha + r_count 
        new_beta = beta + b_count 
        
        new_e_of_theta = new_alpha / (new_alpha + new_beta)
        surprise = ((new_e_of_theta - e_of_theta)**2) / var_theta
        sequences = (first_draw, second_draw)
        
        outcome[surprise] = sequences


#sort by `surprise`
outcome_ordered = OrderedDict()
for surprise in sorted(outcome.keys()):
    outcome_ordered[surprise] = outcome[surprise]

for surprise, (first, second) in outcome_ordered.items():
    print(surprise, ": ", first, second)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this is exactly what I needed!!

Comment: Then please mark it as the answer to your question.

Comment: Btw, note that I added a small edit to sort the entries by `surprise`.

Comment: Thank you so so much!! Btw, is there a way to get those values in order from smallest to largest? If not that's totally fine!! I was just wondering.

Comment: They are already ordered. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OrderedDict` to both have a ordered data structure and make it
possible to map each sequence to a value